# OWA Virtual Paths

Tags: service-application

I'm learning the ropes as an admin and have been installing services the past day or so in my test environment. I chose during the installs of SP and OWA to install to a secondary drive and not use my primary drive. When setting up OWA i was in the IIS pool for my services group as I've shown in this post and all but PowerPoint have stored their data to this secondary drive by default...when setting up the PowerPoint service it defaulted to the primary drive. Does anyone know why this would be the case. Seems odd that the rest of the OWA's were fine going right to the second drive and Powerpoint was the only one. Any ideas on fixing that?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70720667/owavirtualpath.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powerpoint just want to be the exception to the rule so it's decided that instead of installing togetter with the other Office Server parts it wanted to be part of SharePoint. The SharePointRoot (14Hive) is the one part of SharePoint it's very difficult to move to a second drive.
The only way to do it is to change the COMMONPROGRAMFILES environment variable before install as it's always installed into

> %COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14

[See about INSTALLLOCATION here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261668.aspx)

Below this directory are:

- All the OOTB files for SharePoint (Except Office Server parts)
- ULS log files unless moved using Central Admin / PowerShell
- Most of the files from Solution packages when they are deployed

Comment: I figured as much, wasn't finding much out there on the topic that had me thinking otherwise. I don't want to get to custom with the install locations..if it doesn't do it by design i don't really want to risk it just to keep it all in one place. Any resources on information about what is kept in those folders so i can plan recovery around them? Thx!